# SQL Transpose rows to column

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have the following sample from a table

```
+-------------+---+------------------+--+
| Heading1    | 2  | 3               |  |
+-------------+---+------------------+--+
| Cats        | d | 1                |  |
| Cats        | e | 13/01/2000 12:29 |  |
| Dogs        | s | 1                |  |
| Dogs        | e | 13/01/2000 12:29 |  |
| Frogs       | d | 1                |  |
| Frogs       | e | 13/01/2000 12:29 |  |
| Cows        | d | 1                |  |
| Cows        | e | 13/01/2000 12:29 |  |
+-------------+---+------------------+--+
```

I would like column 2's rows to be the distinct headings and contain a row for each unique values from 1 and 3 aand presented like this:

```
+-----------+------+------------------+------+
| Headings: |  d   |        e         |  s   |
+-----------+------+------------------+------+
| Cats      | 1    | 13/01/2000 12:29 | Null |
| Dogs      | Null | 13/01/2000 12:29 | 1    |
| Frogs     | 1    | 13/01/2000 12:29 | Null |
| Cows      | 1    | 13/01/2000 12:29 | Null |
+-----------+------+------------------+------+
```

Any ideas googled it and lost the will with this one :)

EDIT: What i failed to mention was the fact that what becomes the columns is dynamic i.e in this case d, e, s  and can be anything, really appreciate the answers.

Thanks All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transpose the `rows to columns` in two ways

**Method 1 :** `Conditional Aggregate`

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72b97/1)**

```
SELECT Heading1,
       Max(CASE WHEN [2] = 'd' THEN [3] END) 'd',
       Max(CASE WHEN [2] = 'e' THEN [3] END) 'e',
       Max(CASE WHEN [2] = 's' THEN [3] END) 's'
FROM   <tablename>
GROUP  BY Heading1
```

**Method 2 :** `Pivot`

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72b97/3)**

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT *
       FROM   <tablename>) a
      PIVOT (Max([3])
            FOR [2] IN ([d],
                        [e],
                        [s])) piv
```

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is called a [`PIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  It allows you to transform rows into columns.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Heading1,
  (SELECT Heading3 FROM Table2 b WHERE a.Heading1 = b.Heading1 and b.Heading2 = 'd') as d,
  (SELECT Heading3 FROM Table2 b WHERE a.Heading1 = b.Heading1 and b.Heading2 = 'e') as e,
  (SELECT Heading3 FROM Table2 b WHERE a.Heading1 = b.Heading1 and b.Heading2 = 's') as s
INTO Table2
FROM Table1 a
GROUP BY Heading1
```

Comment: Why downvote when the query does exactly what is needed?